# How to use blocks in AutoCAD

Tags: autocad

It is easy to make blocks in AutoCAD. I can make AutoCAD blocks bu symply using *block* command. But I can't use the blocks. I can't insert the blocks that I made. What should I do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CAD drafting software and does not appear to have a GIS component.

Comment: So where should I ask about it? @ChrisW

Comment: I'm actually kind of surprised there isn't a CAD Stack Exchange. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) would be the most appropriate SE site I see, otherwise you'd want to search for a CAD user forum. Martin has posted links to a couple of tutorials below. A Google search on "create autocad block" comes back with many more.

Comment: I too am surprised there isn't a CAD stack exchange. It's very widely used and would be great to have that as a resource. I've used CAD for 12 years and feel I could help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example read this tutroials:

http://www.mycadsite.com/tutorials/level_2/introduction-to-blocks-in-autocad-2-2.htm

http://autocadtutorial.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Use-AutoCAD-Blocks

there are explanations on how to create and insert blocks.